# WIX Combobox Bind Values

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3, wix3.6, wix3.7

I am trying to populate values using custom actions and want to bind the values into combobox which is inside product.wxs.

Can anyone guide me how to bind values if I want to populate a list of countries inside the combobox?

I am struggling with how to pass this value so the values will show inside combox while executing my MSI setup.

Below provide the code which I am trying:

```
    public static ActionResult FillList(Session xiSession)
    {

        Dictionary<string, string> _co = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        _co.Add(String.Empty, String.Empty);
        _co.Add("US", "United States");
        _co.Add("CA", "Canada");
        _co.Add("MX", "Mexico");

        xiSession.Log("Return success");
        return ActionResult.Success;
    }
```

```
    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="SetupProjectComboTest" Level="1">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>
```

```
<UI>
  <UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo" />

  <Dialog Id="MyCustomDlg"  Width="500" Height="260">
    <Control Id="ComboBoxMain" Type="ComboBox" X="10" Y="60" Width="300" Height="17" Property="COUNTRIES" />
    <Control Id="ButtonMain" Type="PushButton" X="320" Y="60" Width="40" Height="17" Text="Show">
      <Publish Property="COMBOVALUEFORMATTED" Order="1"  Value="[COUNTRIES]" />
    </Control>
    <Control Id="LabelMain" Type="Text" X="10" Y="80" Width="360" Height="17" Property="COMBOVALUEFORMATTED" Text="[COMBOVALUEFORMATTED]" />

  </Dialog>
</UI>
```

```
<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="SetupProjectComboTest" />
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
        <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this Component element and the ComponentRef below in order to add resources to this installer. -->
        <!-- <Component Id="ProductComponent"> -->
            <!-- TODO: Insert files, registry keys, and other resources here. -->
        <!-- </Component> -->
    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to insert row into **ComboBox table** to bind the List values. If you open the msi in [ORCA Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you can find the msi tables and rows.

You should include [EnsureTable](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_ensuretable.htm) element if you don’t use any other ComboBox element in your msi.

```
  <EnsureTable Id="ComboBox"/>
```

You can insert the rows from Custom action.

```
  static int index = 1;
 public static void FillComboBox(Session session, string text, string value)
    {
        View view = session.Database.OpenView("SELECT * FROM ComboBox");
        view.Execute();

        Record record = session.Database.CreateRecord(4);
        record.SetString(1, "COUNTRIES");
        record.SetInteger(2, index);
        record.SetString(3, value);
        record.SetString(4, text);

        view.Modify(ViewModifyMode.InsertTemporary, record);
        view.Close();
        index++;
    }
```

Inside the Custom action call the `FillComboBox` method.

```
   public static ActionResult FillList(Session xiSession)
    {

        FillComboBox(xiSession, "US", "United States");
        FillComboBox(xiSession, "CA", "Canada");
        FillComboBox(xiSession, "MX", "Mexico");          

        return ActionResult.Success;
    }
```

Execute the Custom action in **InstallUIsequence** before run that Combo Box dialog.

```
   <InstallUISequence>
     <Custom Action="INSERT_ROWS" After="AppSearch">Not Installed</Custom>
  </InstallUISequence>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried based upon your example and now the combobox is taking binding the value.One more clarity i would like to know is how to show a default value in combobox, say like --Select--.

Comment: You need to set the default value to COUNTRIES property. Form Wix <Property Id="COUNTRIES" Value="United States" /> or from Custom action  xiSession["COUNTRIES"] = "United States";

Comment: Thank you vinoth for your quick reply.this worked for me.One more clarity, how to get a text file path when setup is executing, like

Comment: One more clarity, how to get a text file path when setup is executing,like [CustomAction] public static ActionResult FillList(Session xiSession){string path = @"E:\Mylocation.txt";     
            string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);            
 foreach (string s in readText)
 {    FillComboBox(xiSession, s, s);   }
 xiSession["COUNTRIES"] = "--Select Location--";return ActionResult.Success; } //Can i get store mylocation.txt into application root instead of E location.And how mylocation.txt can be called?

Comment: Post this as a separate question.

Comment: i post the above as seperate question and the link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143806/getting-location-path-wix-installation.Thank you

Comment: can you help me how to save the values from combobox selected text when user click on Next button

Comment: You can get the selected text from Property which is associated with Combo box. Here it is COUNTRIES.