# Getting Location path Wix installation

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3.6, wix3.7

How to get location path if i want to access mylocation.txt file, this file currently is in E:drive.

```
[CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult FillList(Session xiSession)
    {

    //Can i get store mylocation.txt into application root instead of E location
        string path = "Mylocation.txt";

        // Open the file to read from. 
        string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);

        foreach (string s in readText)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(s);
            FillComboBox(xiSession, s, s);
        }
         xiSession["COUNTRIES"] = "--Select Location--";
        return ActionResult.Success;
    }
```

Can i get store mylocation.txt into application root instead of E location.And how mylocation.txt can be called?Basically what i want is to get the values of combox from this text file,once installation is in progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach the `Mylocation.txt` as resource file in Custom action project.  Get more details from this [discussion](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Extract-Binaries-at-Install-Time-td2301189.html).